# How do I give my child a sword?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How do you give your child the wooden sword in skyrim? I have the sword but when I try to give the gift nothing appears and the child says stop teasing

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing appears"?

Comment: I assume he is talking about the window that comes up when you tell a child you have a gift. If you have items that can be gifts for kids in your inventory, they will be listed, and you can select one from the list. If you have no items that can be gifts, the window will be empty, and when you press "back", the child will say "stop teasing".

Comment: I assume it's a bug, because I can gift daggers etc to my children through that window, though I have not tried to give them a wooden sword.

Comment: i've given wooden swords to adpoted children before, so it can be done

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to give him/her the sword, but if it's stolen you won't be able because children have high morality in the game. Either it's stolen (you can see in the upper right of the item description) or it's just a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The sword you'll be giving must be a wooden sword, or a dagger. You can't give stolen swords to children, it has to be exact.

However if this doesn't work, you might encounter a bug:

> Sometimes, when you have a wooden sword or dagger in your inventory and it's not stolen. When you talk to your kid about a gift, it's not in the window, and the child will say to stop teasing you. One solution is to download **Unofficial Patch**. Otherwise wait a few days and talk to your child again.